# Validate build of JWT in more lightweight way than Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex, jwt

I want to validate, if `tokent` that is passed to this method have valid build.

For now, im using `Regex` for it:

```
public bool IsTokenValid(string jwt)
    => new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z0-9-_=]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_=]+\.?[A-Za-z0-9-_.+/=]*$").IsMatch(jwt ?? String.Empty);
```

But `Regex` is extremly slow (too slow for high traffic system with thousands of requests per second)

JWT have some characteriscit part. Do you know how to validate, if JWT passed to this method is builded like standard JWT without using `Regex`?

I know that i can do something like this:

```
try
{
    var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var jwt = jwtHandler?.ReadToken(token); // throw when cant read 
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    _log.Message("cant read")
}
```

But again, throwing exceptions is not what im looking for.

So, do you have any advice, how to validate JWT build in lightweight way?

Comment: Don't construct the regex everytime as constructing a regex is extremely expensive - the matching itself isn't. Save the regex to a singleton/static field and use this to match.

Comment: Is static things are thread-safe?

Comment: Use a compiled regex, or create your own validator out for a **for loop** and a state-machine O(n). Though likely this is an X/Y problem

Comment: @TheGeneral sounds great, could you provide your comment with answer, how it will be look like?

Comment: Yes, the regex class is thread-safe.

Comment: @ckuri even when its `static`?

Comment: If class is thread-safe this usually means that's it's instances are thread-safe, i.e. that you can reuse a (static or non-static) single instance concurrently. So yes, it's still thread-safe when static.

Answer (score 1):

Despite what you might think, your current approach is already the best one:

```
try
{
    var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var jwt = jwtHandler?.ReadToken(token); // throw when cant read 
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    _log.Message("cant read")
}
```

The call to `ReadToken()` above perhaps is deceptively simple, but inside of that call is likely a comparison of the incoming JWT's *checksum* against the full content of the JWT.  See, your main concern with an incoming JWT is that your server can verify that the checksum was a) generated based on the content of the JWT, and b) that the JWT content was not tampered with in any way.  If some malicious user managed to get a hold of one of your user's JWTs, and then try to change some portion of it, such as the claims section, then the checksum would not match, and your above try-catch would throw an exception.

Comment: Sounds great, but im passing JWT that comes with request to another thrd-part service that will validate it in their side. I only want to validate build. I dont care if someone stole JWT and started to change it (they dont have key at all). So, if this approach will work when i want only check standard build of JWT in fast way?

Comment: Not sure, but for certain regex alone won't help much here.